# How to access files on SD card after upgrading to Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, photos, micro-sd, lumia-640-xl, windows-10-upgrade

I recently upgraded a Nokia Lumia 640 XL to Windows 10 Mobile. I need to know how to access photos that were saved to micro SD card for viewing on phone.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Files** app to access files and folders on you SD Card. You'll find it in the app list of your Windows 10 Mobile device.

1. Tap the <kbd>☰</kbd> in the upper left corner.
2. Pick the SD Card

   - Find your photos.

Answer (score 0):

The phone should automatically detect a "Pictures" folder (and a "Camera Roll" subfolder) on your SD card. You can specifically tell it to use that folder if you want to, though.

1. Open `Settings` on the phone.
2. Go to the search box and type "storage"; select the option that comes up and jump to Win10 Mobile's version of "Storage Sense".
3. Select the types of data you want to have stored on the SD card (in particular, tell the phone to put pictures, etc. there).

You should be able to see photos from the card within the Pictures app (or directly from the Camera app) and newly-taken photos should appear on the card.